# history.js is rewriting urls with hash tags

Tags: javascript, history.js

I've got jquery history.js working but I'd like to force hash tags to be used.  I've tried setting `History.options.html4Mode=true` but this doesn't work.

The reason I need this is that upon page refresh, the url in the browser is not valid.  I'm working around a strange backend and require these urls.

What happens when I use hash tags is:

1)  Initial state: `http://localhost/<script_path>/<param1>?get&file=<html_file>`

2) `History.pushSate(null, null, http://<script_path/<parm>?get&file=<html_file>#/<parm>/<parm>?<more parms>`

3) After `History.pushState: http://localhost/<parm>/<parm>?<more parms>`

edit: forgot to mention that if I remove the hash it appends everything after the file perfectly.

edit 2: seems to be some interaction between history and jquery. I think history is pushing the url i give it. Stepping through it right now.

edit 3: solved. historyjs won't work for this project- i have to use location.hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you are doing is adding a hash onto the existing URL, you should set `location.hash`.  Use pushState for changing the pathName without reloading the page.

UPDATE: history.js uses hashes in order to support older browsers.  So passing in a hashed URL to history.js simply doesn't make sense (eg. what happens on older browsers?).

My suggestion is to use another query string parameter to hold the new URL.  You will need to encode any path-like values:

```
var path2 = "/script_path/param1?more=params&even_more=params";
var newUrl = "/script_path/param1?get&file=html_file&path=" + encodeURI( path2 );
History.pushSate(null, null, newUrl);
```

... or you could take advantage of the API (no encoding needed):

```
var path2 = "/script_path/param1?more=params&even_more=params";
var newUrl = "/script_path/param1?get&file=html_file";
History.pushSate({path: path2}, null, newUrl);
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work for clicking links but not reloading. My question is still why is history.js stripping out everything but the server and the hash?

Comment: I had built my own html 5 plugin that worked great but i need to support html 4 browsers.  This plugin seems like the way to go if i can get it figured out O.o

Comment: Thanks a lot man.  Funny thing is it works perfectly in older browsers (ie8/9/10) (maybe that's what you are saying).  I really appreciate the help.  I will make these changes tomorrow.

I'd up-vote if I had the rep.  I've marked this as solved. You've given me a tonne of help I should be able to take it from here. :)

Comment: Christ I'm slow- for my purposes I just need to change the hash.  Thanks for the help :)